# Is there a way to have mui v5 render the classnames without the css-xxx prefix?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

mui has been a pleasure to work with.  It seems "everyone has their way" of doing react styling and layout.  As a library developer, the task of managing this flexibility must be immense.

"My way" of customizing mui was to work with the global theme.  So I created class names to add to say the `MuiContainer`.  I relied on the selectors in the `overrides`, now mui component-specific `styleOverrides` prop.

My selectors are not working because of the following:

```css
// v4 class names
.MuiContainer-root

// v5 class names
.css-1oqqzyl-MuiContainer-root
```

Is there a way to get the theme engine to render the class names the same way?  For instance, is this evidence of mui reliance on `emotion`?

As an aside, when rendered in v4 the class names includes my custom classes:

```css
.MuiContainer-root.Luci-AppLayout.root
```

Per the addendum, in v5 there are 3 sets of class names for a given element:

- mui without prefix
- mui with prefix (not present in v4)
- my custom classes "as-is"

Only the  mui with prefix show-up in the "inspection" window; i.e., revealing the classes actually rendered to style the element.

### Addendum

Per a comment from [@Ryan Cogswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7495930/ryan-cogswell), the *two* versions of the class names are rendered in the html.  However, in the inspection window of the dev-tools, the only version of the class used to style the element, is the class with the prefix.

Here is my first go at replicating the problem in the sandbox. Look in the dev-tools inspector.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sad-varahamihira-pv73t5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here's the code from the sandbox:

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import "./styles.css";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  ccomponents: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          color: "red",
          "&.Custom": {
            color: "green"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Button className="Custom">Testing</Button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: The global class names (such as `.MuiContainer-root`) are still present in v5 in addition to the emotion-generated class names.

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of what you are trying to do in the theme.

Comment: @Ryan Cogswell Thank you.  You are right.  I missed that *And/but* in the inspection window the class names are as a described with the prefix.  Is this evidence of needing to change the sequence of css interpretation? -- I will augment the post with more to reveal more of the task in detail.

Comment: The css is not being generated.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with the **smallest amount of code** necessary to reproduce the problem (e.g. override **one** CSS property on one type of element).

Comment: @RyanCogswell I have an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Note, I have this working in v4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two issues with the code in your sandbox.

1. You had `ccomponents` in your theme instead of `components`. I suspect this double `c` was just a typo specific to your sandbox and probably isn't in your real code.
2. You were importing the `ThemeProvider` from `"@mui/styles"`. You should be importing it from `"@mui/material/styles"` instead. `"@mui/styles"` is for the legacy JSS styling approach and using that [`ThemeProvider`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.6.3/packages/mui-styles/src/ThemeProvider/index.js#L1) does not make the theme visible to the `"@mui/material"` styling engine. The `ThemeProvider` in `"@mui/material/styles"` places the theme into two different contexts -- one is the [same as what `@mui/styles` uses](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.6.3/packages/mui-system/src/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js#L3), the other [provides the theme to the styling engine](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.6.3/packages/mui-system/src/ThemeProvider/ThemeProvider.js#L5).

Here's a working version of your sandbox:

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          color: "red",
          "&.Custom": {
            color: "green"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Button className="Custom">Testing</Button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit condescending-dew-r1kwc1]

Comment: Your diagnosis is spot-on.  I was using `{ ThemeProvider } from '@mui/styles'`.  I should have been using `@mui/material/styles`... Your explanation was helpful. It makes me wonder if this is not a case study: benefit of being explicit in the design by perhaps naming it: `@mui/jss-styles` or the like.